# Repeatedly extract every second and third line of a file with 3-line data blocks

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file where I have data in 3-line sets. I want the 2nd and 3rd line from each set.
How do I get that?

For an example from: [set no][no of line in set]

```
11
12
13
21
22
23
31
32
33
```

I want:

```
12
13
22
23
32
33
```

and so on.

I have tried a few options but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: What have you tried, what else is to be found on the lines. Are the files just repeating like that so one can say you need every second and third line?

Comment: `sed '1~3d'` will output each second and third lines

Answer (score 2):

With POSIX awk:

```
awk '!(FNR%3==1)' <file
```

With POSIX sed:

```
sed -e '1d;n;n;d' <file
```

With GNU sed:

```
sed -e '1~3d' <file
```